# why isn't the dates on this sheet highlighting although the value is the same

Tags: vba, excel

I've got a macro code to highlight cells in a sheet where the value comes from another sheet upon a button click on a separate sheet but it is returning value can't be found/none found when the value on both sheets is actually the same.

The value of the cell is a date value.

the 1st is the intended sheet and the 2nd one is the code

[intended sheet to highlight cells](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zP0Z4.png)

```
Sub HighlightSpecificValue()
    Dim fnd As String, FirstFound As String
    Dim FoundCell As Range, rng As Range
    Dim myRange As Range, LastCell As Range
    fnd = Range("H9").Value
    Sheets("PO copy").Select
    Set myRange = ActiveSheet.UsedRange
    Set LastCell = myRange.Cells(myRange.Cells.Count)
    Set FoundCell = myRange.Find(what:=fnd, after:=LastCell)
    If Not FoundCell Is Nothing Then
        FirstFound = FoundCell.Address
    Else
        GoTo NothingFound
    End If  
    Set rng = FoundCell
    Do Until FoundCell Is Nothing
        Set FoundCell = myRange.FindNext(after:=FoundCell)
        Set rng = Union(rng, FoundCell)
        If FoundCell.Address = FirstFound Then Exit Do
    Loop
    rng.Interior.Color = RGB(255, 255, 0)
    Exit Sub
NothingFound:
    MsgBox "No cells containing: " & fnd & " were found in this worksheet"
End Sub
```

Comment: Without code to test / correct it will be hard to help you.  Try pasting your code into the question instead of just including a picture of it.  (Have you ever tried accurately retyping a page full of someone else's code in order to test it?)

Comment: Just a sec will type it out. it works for other types of things less the date. i tried on empty cells and etc but i just can't understand why it doesn't work for date.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A couple of things need to be fixed:

- You shouldn't try to compare a `String` to a cell containing a date - so it will be best to define `fnd` as a `Variant`
- You are currently not specifying whether to look at values or formulas when doing the `Find`, or whether to look at part or the whole of the value - you should explicitly define those in order to avoid confusion due to Excel using whatever the user last used

I believe the following, slightly modified, code should work:

```
Sub HighlightSpecificValue()
    Dim fnd As Variant, FirstFound As String
    Dim FoundCell As Range, rng As Range
    Dim myRange As Range, LastCell As Range
    fnd = Range("H9").Value
    Sheets("PO copy").Select
    Set myRange = ActiveSheet.UsedRange
    Set LastCell = myRange.Cells(myRange.Cells.Count)
    Set FoundCell = myRange.Find(what:=fnd, _
                                 after:=LastCell, _
                                 LookIn:=xlValues, _
                                 LookAt:=xlWhole)
    If Not FoundCell Is Nothing Then
        FirstFound = FoundCell.Address
    Else
        GoTo NothingFound
    End If  
    Set rng = FoundCell
    Do Until FoundCell Is Nothing
        Set FoundCell = myRange.FindNext(after:=FoundCell)
        Set rng = Union(rng, FoundCell)
        If FoundCell.Address = FirstFound Then Exit Do
    Loop
    rng.Interior.Color = RGB(255, 255, 0)
    Exit Sub
NothingFound:
    MsgBox "No cells containing: " & fnd & " were found in this worksheet"
End Sub
```

Comment: i did a test and put on the original code i had, fnd =  "9 May 2017" and it works fine. but taking the cell value Range("H9").Value however i believe converts it to this format 9/5/2017 and thus unable to search for the correct value(this is what i'm guessing). i tried to do adjust the find function as you suggested but it still can't detect the necessary value out. am i missing something?

Comment: @SamuelNg Is it possible that sheet "PO copy" contains dates **with times**?

Comment: @SamuelNg Do you have actual dates on sheet "PO copy", or just text that looks like dates?  (`Range("H9").Value` won't convert it to `9/5/2017` - it should convert it to something like `42864`.  No, maybe it does, but you need it to think it is a date in order to match against cells containing dates.)

Comment: the cells in PO Copy are formatted to date format. and the cell which i'm searching from is also as such.

Comment: @SamuelNg Temporarily change the cells in "PO Copy" to be `General` format, and let me know whether they change to 5-digit numbers or whether they continue looking like dates.

Comment: it will be 5 digit numbers

Comment: @SamuelNg Hmm - if they are 5 digit numbers, they are dates, and the code should have worked.  (I tested it before posting and it successfully matched dates.)  And, if they are dates, setting `fnd` to `"9 May 2017"` should have failed.  I think I'm out of ideas.

Comment: let me try again to see if i can figure it out. its been awhile since i worked on excel vba codes. thus got alot of things to refresh on. will let u know if i'm able to figure it out. thanks for your time :)

Comment: @SamuelNg I'll leave this page open and check it when I wake up in the morning to see if you (or anyone else) solved it.

Comment: Managed to figure it out..     instead of xlValues, i changed it over to xlFormulas and it worked perfectly. thanks alot!

Set FoundCell = myRange.Find(what:=fnd, _
                                 after:=LastCell, _
                                 LookIn:=xlFormulas, _
                                 LookAt:=xlWhole)